# Azure Blob storage (GUI) client for linux

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Is there a GUI based client for Azure Blob storage that can run on Linux?

I found many client that runs on Windows and couple of web based clients but I'm looking for something like [Azure Explorer](http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's a desktop based client for Linux. I would recommend trying out Zud.io (https://zud.io/). This is a browser based storage explorer and has capability to manage blobs, tables and queues.

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for some desktop application.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't today. May be there's an opportunity here :). I haven't worked on Linux so let me ask you a question: Would a technology like roozz (http://www.roozz.com/) work in Linux?

Comment: I'm not sure, it seems like the download is a *.exe file. I would expect someone to develop such cross using Java.

Comment: Hi, I make Zudio. Can I ask why you specifically want a desktop application? Is there something the browser-based app can't do? One of the goals for Zudio was to provide quality tooling on non-Windows devices, including Linux.

Comment: This answer is now useless since zud.io seems to be dead (the domain is up for sale)

Comment: @ChrisWue...Please look at the date when this question was answered (almost 7 years ago).

Comment: BTW, you can take a look at Microsoft Storage Explorer.

Comment: Sure, I'm simply pointing out that this answer no longer serves any useful purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's something close, that should work with no or *very little* code.  I'm posting this since you mentioned Java.

[Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/) is a Virtual File-System library that supports multiple backends such as FTP, SFTP, S3, etc. etc.  There is also a GUI for Apache VFS called [Commons VFS - UI](http://commons-vfs-ui.sourceforge.net/).  This GUI uses Apache VFS to access a wide range of virtual file-systems.

I wrote an Apache VFS Provider for Microsoft Azure called VFS-Azure that you can find at https://github.com/kervinpierre/vfs-azure .

There is no reason someone couldn't easily add VFS-Azure provider to the list of known providers in Commons VFS UI.  I'll take a look when I have more time in my schedule but I suspect that's something that can easily be completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://storageexplorer.com/ it is cross platform.

Comment: Beware of the fact that there are no explicit installation instructions. check some of these out:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/32923909-add-the-installation-instructions-for-the-linux-ve